# Grid action button selection

Tags: buttons, grid, actions

**Problem statement:**
[image]
1. Need to select individual row and Copy.
2. Need to select multiple rows and Copy.
3. Need to select items from different page (Pagination) and Copy.
4. Need to select all items in the grid(Not just page 1, but all page 1 to end)and Copy.

The current design allows single row single by directly clicking on copy button in action column where as multiple selection by selecting checkbox and then click on copy button at bottom bar. Not happy!!

Do we have to keep single place of action button here? For single/multiple selection, Select (checkbox) and then copy from bottom bar copy button?
How do we copy items from different page?

Any suggestions are much appreciated and happy to help with further details if needed.

Comment: You haven't accepted any answer till date; maybe you are not aware of it. So, do read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Let the user select as many records they want to; just let the count below keep increasing/decreasing as per selection/deselection. You won't require the actions column if there is only one action on the grid like 'Copy'.

I'm assuming it's a popup so the placement of count and 'Copy Selected' button is ok. If this is not a popup then consider moving the feedback and action items on top of the grid. Refer Gmail Grid and Actions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) Like the way u removed action column...but is this the good practice - selection and then action button?

Comment: @Sunilkv Yes, it is. If it wasn't then Gmail wouldn't have implemented it. You can also take the advantage of tons of users already being familiar to this practice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution : I tried my best to explain you the solution with example shown below.[image: Initially Screen would look like this for example.]

This is the initial screen.

[image]

Screen having both single and multiple copy operation interface.

But one thing is there, you have to put validation that once after selection of row (ex. in single/multiple copy) unless and until user press the 'copy now' button, data will not be updated.

AND in case of multiple copy you can select the rows of another page because on paging only table portion will be changed remaining will be as it is. so you can select multiple rows from different page also.

Comment: I appreciate your time :) But how different is your design ("Copy and Select") from "Select and copy" method? Why cant 1 copy button work for both single and multiple copy?"

Comment: Why would you keep 'Select' as a last column of the grid? And where there is pagination; is the first Sr. No. column required?

Comment: I used first **select option to copy(i.e single/multiple copy)** then rows selection will be enable. Because if you give select column initially then user will get confused that what is the use of select and where to submit after selection. So I removed 'select' column initially. When user choose option then only it will be displayed so user easily can understand that now next step is to select the row.  When user click on any option to copy at that time button will be change from "single/multiple copy" to "copy now" so user will get idea that after selection he/she have to click here to copy.

Comment: and yes you can put **Select ** first also that is your choice. and here functionality of copy was important so I have left intentionally pagination here because all know how pagination works so.